# Need help with extending my Perl module

Tags: perl, perl-module, extend

I am trying to extend my company specific BaseClass (Acme::BaseClass) but whenever I:

```
package Manager;
use strict;
use warnings;
use base qw(Acme::BaseClass)
sub new { ...
```

it gives me the error:

```
Base class package "Acme::BaseClass" is empty.
```

But in my script I can use the package fine:

```
use Acme::BaseClass;
my $bc = BaseClass->new("myname");
$bc->prnt(); # prints "myname"
exit;
```

This is my first time trying to inherit in Perl so maybe I am missing something basic?

NOTES:

- I have tried using "parent" and it also does not work
- I tried to use the old school :

  BEGIN {
     require Acme::BaseClass;
     push @ISA, qw(Acme::BaseClass);
  }

I am unsure how to do these correctly either. Hopefully it is something simple I am missing. If nobody can answer it I will add more details.

Comment: What happens when you do: `eval { require Acme::BaseClass }; print "Error: $@\n";`

Comment: Also, your code looks suspicious. Thescript example should say `
my $bc = Acme::BaseClass->new("myname");`

Comment: Also, your code looks suspicious. Thescript example should say `
my $bc = Acme::BaseClass->new("myname");`

Comment: Yes, when I scoped it correctly I had to append the "Acme::" to the new line in the script.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Judging from your code sample, it sounds like `Acme/BaseClass.pm` has something like this in it

```
package BaseClass;

....

1;
```

and it needs

```
package Acme::BaseClass;

....

1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the child class cannot find the BaseClass module but your test script can. Check @INC is setup correctly so that both can find your module.

Comment: Understood, Not available to me. Even through CPAN.